# How to call FooterView method

Tags: javascript, yui

According to the Alloy UI API, the FooterView class has a method called `refreshFooter()` which
 **Refreshes the summary items in the footer view and populates the footer elements based on the current "data" contents.**

I am trying to figure out how to call this function after a certain event, not sure how to make the call since the `footerView` is defined as an attribute. Here is my Datatable:

```
var dataTable = new Y.DataTable({
    columns: columns,
    height: '95%',
    footerView:   Y.FooterView, 
    footerConfig: {
       fixed:   true,
       heading: {
           colspan:    5,
           content:    "Number of Records : {row_count}" 
       }
   }
```

});

I've tried placing the `footerView` into a variable and invoking but, but no luck. Any ideas on how to execute this function?

Source: http://stlsmiths.github.io/new-gallery/classes/Y.FooterView.html#method_refreshFooter

Answer (score -1):

Basically tables require two kinds of information, table columns and data. Pass both into your Data Table after columns and data, and **don't forget to render it!** . I think you are not rendering it. **Try it !** **GoodLuck!**

```
    YUI().use(
  'aui-datatable',
  function(Y) {
    var columns = [
      name,
      age
    ];

    var data = [
      {
        name: 'Bob',
        age: '28'
      },
      {
        name: 'Joe',
        age: '72'
      },
      {
        name: 'Sarah',
        age: '35'
      }
    ];

    new Y.DataTable(
      {
        columns: columns,
        data: data
      }
    ).render("#myDataTable");
  }
);
```

**#myDataTable** is the div that you want to render.

Comment: I render my table later on in the code and the columns & data are displayed fine as is the footerView. I'm simply trying to figure out how to call the specific footerView function at any given time